# Java: return List of objects of the type that calls the method

Tags: java, jdbc, reflection

what i am trying to do is return a java List of objects of any type that calls the method.

```
List<Playlist> playlist = Table.selectAll();
```

Those java objects (in this case Playlist) should each contain a row of values from my SQL ResultSet.

```
public class Table extends Database {

    public List<this> selectAll() {
        List<this> newList = new List<this>();

        String tableName = this.getClass().getSimpleName().toLowerCase();
        Field[] fields = this.getClass().getDeclaredFields();

        Connection connection = getConnection();
        PreparedStatement preStat = null;
        ResultSet resultSet = null;

        try {
            preStat = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM " + tableName);
            resultSet = getFromDB(preStat);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // create a list of Objects of class ‘this’ (in this case Playlist) 
        // and using the fields obtained from .getDeclaredFields() 
        // assign values to each Object from the ‘preStat’ results 
        // then put those objects into ‘newList’

        return newList;
    }

}
```

What am I doing wrong here? should I pass in a List to the method instead of getting a return back, but then how would I create an Object from each ResultSet, assign it values using .getDeclaredFields() then assign the object to the List?

Comment: Your table name is `Table`? That's a poor choice of a table name!

Answer (score 0):

```
List<this> newList = new List<this>();
```

is not going to work, it must be

```
List<PlayList> newList = new List<>();
```

Then in your comments do

```
while (resultSet.next()) {
    PlayList l = new PlayList();
    l.setId(resultSet.getInt(1));
    l.setYourStringField(resultSet.getString(2));
    l.setAnotherStringField(resultSet.getString(3));
    newList.add(l);
}

resultSet.close();
preStat.close();
connection.close();
```

Being `setId`, `setYourStringField` and `setAnotherStringField` property setters of your PlayList object.